# conflicting return type for Init()

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, init

I have a MasterProcess which is a specialization of a general process concept and the MasterDocument class is supposed to consider several different specializations of MasterProcess in a possible generic way. I am using I am using virtual void Init() to achieve this functionality. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class BaseMasterProcess {

protected:

int processID;  
int num_of_Questions;  
double min_Threshold_Score_for_Process;  
double total_Process_Score;  
double overall_Audit_Value;
int question;
pair <int,double> answer;

//define all the variable used in any sub-class 
int question1;
int question2;
int question3;
int question4;
int question5;
double question1_Weightage;
double question2_Weightage;
double question3_Weightage;
double question4_Weightage;
double question5_Weightage;
int passing_Score;
pair <int,double> answer1_Option1;  
pair <int,double> answer1_Option2; 
pair <int,double> answer1_Option3;
pair <int,double> answer2_Option1;  
pair <int,double> answer2_Option2; 
pair <int,double> answer2_Option3;
pair <int,double> answer3_Option1;  
pair <int,double> answer3_Option2; 
pair <int,double> answer3_Option3;
pair <int,double> answer4_Option1;  
pair <int,double> answer4_Option2; 
pair <int,double> answer4_Option3;
pair <int,double> answer5_Option1;  
pair <int,double> answer5_Option2; 
pair <int,double> answer5_Option3;

public:
virtual void Init();
virtual double getQuestionWeightage(int ques) = 0;
virtual double getAnswerScore(int ques, int ans) = 0; 
int getNumQuestions()
{
    return num_of_Questions;
}
int getProcesssID()
{
    return processID;
}
double getMinThresholdScore()
{
    return min_Threshold_Score_for_Process;
}
double overallAuditValue()
{
    return overall_Audit_Value; 
}
};

class ConcreteMasterProcess1 : public BaseMasterProcess
{
public:
    Init()
    {
processID = 10; 
num_of_Questions = 3;  
passing_Score = 70;  
min_Threshold_Score_for_Process = 0.7; 
overall_Audit_Value = 0.1;

question1 = 1; 
question1_Weightage = 0.3;  
answer1_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.3); 
answer1_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);

question2 = 2; 
question2_Weightage = 0.3; 
answer2_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.3); 
answer2_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);


question3 = 3;
question3_Weightage = 0.4; 
answer3_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.4); 
answer3_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);
}

double getQuestionWeightage(int ques)
{
switch (ques)
{
    case 1:
        return question1_Weightage;
    case 2:
        return question2_Weightage;
    case 3:
        return question3_Weightage;
}

double getAnswerScore(int ques, int ans) 
{
    if (ques == question1 && ans == answer1_Option1.first)
        return answer1_Option1.second;
    else if (ques == question1 && ans == answer1_Option2.first)
        return answer1_Option2.second; 
    else if (ques == question2 && ans == answer2_Option1.first)
        return answer2_Option1.second;
    else if (ques == question2 && ans == answer2_Option2.first)
        return answer2_Option2.second;
    else if (ques == question3 && ans == answer3_Option1.first)
        return answer3_Option1.second;
    else 
        return answer3_Option2.second;

}   
};

class ConcreteMasterProcess2 : public BaseMasterProcess
{
    Init()
    {
processID = 11; 
num_of_Questions = 4;  
passing_Score = 70;  
min_Threshold_Score_for_Process = 0.75; 
overall_Audit_Value = 0.1;

question1 = 1; 
question1_Weightage = 0.25;  
answer1_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.25); 
answer1_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);

question2 = 2; 
question2_Weightage = 0.25; 
answer2_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.25); 
answer2_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);
answer2_Option3 = make_pair (3,0.15);

question3 = 3;
question3_Weightage = 0.25; 
answer3_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.25); 
answer3_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);

question4 = 4;
question4_Weightage = 0.2; 
answer4_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.2); 
answer4_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);

question5 = 5;
question5_Weightage = 0.2; 
answer5_Option1 = make_pair (1,0.2); 
answer5_Option2 = make_pair (2,0.0);
}

double getQuestionWeightage(int ques)
{
switch (ques)
{
    case 1:
        return question1_Weightage;
        break;
    case 2:
        return question2_Weightage;
        break;
    case 3:
        return question3_Weightage;
        break;
    case 4:
        return question4_Weightage;
        break;
}

double getAnswerScore(int ques, int ans) 
{
    if (ques == question1 && ans == answer1_Option1.first)
        return answer1_Option1.second;
    else if (ques == question1 && ans == answer1_Option2.first)
        return answer1_Option2.second; 
    else if (ques == question2 && ans == answer2_Option1.first)
        return answer2_Option1.second;
    else if (ques == question2 && ans == answer2_Option2.first)
        return answer2_Option2.second;
    else if (ques == question2 && ans == answer2_Option3.first)
        return answer2_Option3.second;
    else if (ques == question3 && ans == answer3_Option1.first)
        return answer3_Option1.second;
    else if (ques == question3 && ans == answer3_Option2.first)
        return answer3_Option2.second;
    else if (ques == question4 && ans == answer4_Option1.first)
        return answer4_Option1.second;
    else
        return answer4_Option2.second;

}   
};
class MasterDocument
{

std::vector<BaseMasterProcess*> myProcessList;
void AddProcess(BaseMasterProcess* iProcess)
{
myProcessList.push_back(iProcess);
}
void foo()
{
//myProcessList[...]->Method1(); //do something without knowing which specific concrete  class the process belongs to..
}
};

int main ()
{
MasterDocument master_doc;
cout << master_doc.myProcessList.size();

}
}
```

I get the following errors while compiling it.

```
**MD.cxx:81:11: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Init’ with no type [-fpermissive]
MD.cxx:138:11: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Init’ with no type [-fpermissive]
MD.cxx:138:6: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual int ConcreteMasterProcess1::ConcreteMasterProcess2::Init()’
MD.cxx:57:15: error:   overriding ‘virtual void BaseMasterProcess::Init()’
MD.cxx:582:1: error: expected ‘;’ after class definition
MD.cxx:582:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
MD.cxx:81:6: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual int ConcreteMasterProcess1::Init()’
MD.cxx:57:15: error:   overriding ‘virtual void BaseMasterProcess::Init()’
MD.cxx: In member function ‘virtual double ConcreteMasterProcess1::getQuestionWeightage(int)’:
MD.cxx:119:2: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
MD.cxx: In member function ‘virtual double ConcreteMasterProcess1::ConcreteMasterProcess2::getQuestionWeightage(int)’:
MD.cxx:192:2: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
MD.cxx: At global scope:
MD.cxx:580:1: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input**
```

Comment: Your missing closing brackets `}` after your switch statements and your accessing a private member of `MasterDocument` in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're trying to provide a constructor for the class `ConcreteMasterProcess2`. You should do it this way:

```
class ConcreteMasterProcess2 : public BaseMasterProcess {
public:
    ConcreteMasterProcess2() {
         /* ... */
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out another way. I had to put the void return type in sub-classes. Although declaring it as a constructor also works.

Answer (score 2):

Your Init method in ConcreteMasterProcess1 has no return type specified.  Perhaps you are getting it mixed up with a constructor.

Comment: How do I specify the return type of Init(). All I want is that the Init() method creates the all the ConcereteMasterProcess when the MasterDocument object is created in the main

Comment: Put "void" in front of Init().  You did this in BaseMasterProcess, but you have to do it for the derived classes also.

Comment: oops my bad. thanks for pointing out the silly mistake. However, when I try to access the public member of the BaseClass, I am getting this error.
In member function ‘virtual double ConcreteMasterProcess1::getQuestionWeightage(int)’:
MD.cxx:119:2: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Comment: @Atif: Read my comment above, you have two missing brackets after your functions and one extraneous bracket at the end.

Comment: @Jesse Good: Thanks for pointing out bro. Guess I need to go to bed since I am making silly mistakes.